# sorting a vector of structs

Tags: c++, sorting, vector

I have a `vector<data> info` where `data` is defined as:

```
struct data{
    string word;
    int number;
};
```

I need to sort `info` by the length of the word strings. Is there a quick and simple way to do it?

Answer (score 116, accepted):

Use a comparison function:

```
bool compareByLength(const data &a, const data &b)
{
    return a.word.size() < b.word.size();
}
```

and then use [`std::sort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) in the header `#include <algorithm>`:

```
std::sort(info.begin(), info.end(), compareByLength);
```

Comment: What if I wish to sort the vector in a lexicographic manner according to the string filed ? (I'm using C++11 if it matters). Is there a way to approach it other than defining a comparison function /use lambda and instead use the integral operator< of std::string ? Below is my solution using lambda:     
                                                                            
    sort(info.begin(),info.end(), [](const data& d1, const data& d2)
    {
        return (d1.word.compare(d2.word) < 0);
    });

Answer (score 49):

Just make a comparison function/functor:

```
bool my_cmp(const data& a, const data& b)
{
    // smallest comes first
    return a.word.size() < b.word.size();
}

std::sort(info.begin(), info.end(), my_cmp);
```

Or provide an `bool operator<(const data& a) const` in your `data` class:

```
struct data {
    string word;
    int number;

    bool operator<(const data& a) const
    {
        return word.size() < a.word.size();
    }
};
```

or non-member as Fred said:

```
struct data {
    string word;
    int number;
};

bool operator<(const data& a, const data& b)
{
    return a.word.size() < b.word.size();
}
```

and just call `std::sort()`:

```
std::sort(info.begin(), info.end());
```

Comment: Op< should be a non-member and number should probably be considered in op< so other algorithms, such as std::unique, behave as expected when used with the default std::less; otherwise spot on.

Comment: Why `operator<()` should be non-member?

Comment: @MuriloVasconcelos: So implicit conversions apply to the left-hand side.

Comment: IMHO, you shouldn't use operator overloading to wrap behaviour that isn't immediately intuitive.  In this situation, it doesn't really make any sense to say that `data a` is "less than" `data b` if its string member is shorter, so I wouldn't use `operator<` to express that idea.

Comment: Added but I don't see problem with the "member-way"

Comment: In this case I agree with you and is why I write about the "function-way" first and then I explained the other ways for learning purposes.

Comment: @MuriloVasconcelos Why we need `const` function for `operator <` ?

Answer (score 5):

Yes:  you can sort using a custom comparison function:

```
std::sort(info.begin(), info.end(), my_custom_comparison);
```

`my_custom_comparison` needs to be a function or a class with an `operator()` overload (a functor) that takes two `data` objects and returns a `bool` indicating whether the first is ordered prior to the second (i.e., `first < second`).  Alternatively, you can overload `operator<` for your class type `data`; `operator<` is the default ordering used by `std::sort`.

Either way, the comparison function must yield a [strict weak ordering](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/StrictWeakOrdering.html) of the elements.

Answer (score 4):

As others have mentioned, you could use a comparison function, but you can also overload the < operator and the default `less<T>` functor will work as well:

```
struct data {
    string word;
    int number;
    bool operator < (const data& rhs) const {
        return word.size() < rhs.word.size();
    }
};
```

Then it's just:

```
std::sort(info.begin(), info.end());
```

**Edit**

As James McNellis pointed out, `sort` does not actually use the `less<T>` functor by default. However, the rest of the statement that the `less<T>` functor will work as well is still correct, which means that if you wanted to put `struct data`s into a `std::map` or `std::set` this would still work, but the other answers which provide a comparison function would need additional code to work with either.

Comment: Interestingly, while `std::map` and `std::set` default to using `std::less<T>`, `std::sort` and the rest of the sorting functions default to using `operator<`.  You'll only notice a difference if you specialize `std::less` to do something other than what `operator<` does.

Comment: When I said "you'll only notice a difference if...," I was wrong.  You'll also notice a difference if you have a container of pointers, e.g. `std::vector<int*> v; v.insert(new int); v.insert(new int); std::sort(v.begin(), v.end());`, since the behavior is undefined if you compare unrelated pointers using `<`.  That said, why you'd want to sort a container of pointers by the pointer value and not the value of the pointed-to object, I don't know.