# Unable to execute std::sort correctly

Tags: c++, sorting, c++11

After doing some research I have resigned to ask what is going wrong with `std::sort`.

Following Oliver Charlesworth advice from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4892680/sorting-a-vector-of-structs) I created a comparative, included the algorithm header and called `std::sort` in my function. I am still getting errors. Probably an oversight but still.

Errors:

> Error C2780 void std::sort(_RanIt,_RanIt)': expects 2 arguments - 3 provided
>
> Error C2672   'std::sort': no matching overloaded function found
>
> Error C3867   'ImageEvaluator::comparator': non-standard syntax; use '&' to create a pointer to member

Struct:

```
struct numLocWidth
{
    int width;
    int number;
    int location;
};
```

Comparative:

```
bool comparator(const numLocWidth &a, const numLocWidth &b) 
{ 
    return a.location < b.location; 
}
```

Function:

```
if (tempMax > minAcceptableValue)
{
    tempLocAndVal.location = max_Pot_Loc.x;
    tempLocAndVal.number = i - 1;
    tempLocAndVal.width = templates[7][i].size().width;
    foundNumbers.push_back(tempLocAndVal);
    std::sort(foundNumbers.begin(), foundNumbers.end(), comparator);                
}
```

Not sure what is going on here and have been scratching my head for a bit. I could write my own sort function but I'm pretty sure this way will be more efficient.

Comment: It looks like `comparator` is a non-static class member function. Make it static or non-member.

Comment: Please see [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: You haven't provided enough information.   From the error messages, it appears that your `comparator()` is a non-static member function of some class.    The variant of `std::sort()` which accepts a comparator as the third argument requires that comparator to be a binary function (i.e. either a static member of a class, or a non-member function that accepts the required arguments).

Comment: Please see, https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Thanks both of you. please put your answers up so I can mark as solved.

Comment: Both VTT and Peter are correct I should of made static.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As VTT and Peter rightly pointed out, my comparative needed to be marked as static because it was a member of a class.

More information on this can be found [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/Compare) under requirements and BinaryPredicates.

Thanks for the help

Solution.
From:

```
bool comparator(const numLocWidth &a, const numLocWidth &b) 
{ 
    return a.location < b.location; 
}
```

To:

```
static bool comparator(const numLocWidth &a, const numLocWidth &b) 
{ 
    return a.location < b.location; 
}
```

Thanks again for the help